# Build failure with Google Android Tutorial

Tags: java, android, eclipse, macos, ant

I am trying to complete the android tutorial series provided by Google using command line arguments. I have:

1. Installed the latest version of the ADT/Eclipse environment
2. Installed the various add-ons using the SDK manager to allow use of Android 2.2 (inline with the version used in the Tutorial)
3. Installed Ant 1.8 (on Mac OsX 10.9.1 with Java 1.6)
4. Successfully completed the first Google tutorial (ie compiling Hello World)

When moving to the second part of the tutorial ("Building a Simple User Interface"), however, I run into build problems when I get to the compile stage of that particular tutorial. I have replicated exactly the code provided in the tutorial site (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html) but always get the following compile-time errors:

```
  Buildfile: /Users/admin/Dropbox/CODING/ANDROID/work/build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.3.0
 [checkenv] Installed at /Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: MyFirstApp
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.0.1
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for MyFirstApp...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.2.2
[gettarget] API level:        17
[gettarget] WARNING: No minSdkVersion value set. Application will install on all Android versions.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/admin/Dropbox/CODING/ANDROID/work/bin/rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/admin/Dropbox/CODING/ANDROID/work/bin/rsLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for MyFirstApp...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...
   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] No changes in the AndroidManifest files.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] No changed resources. R.java and Manifest.java untouched.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 4 source files to /Users/admin/Dropbox/CODING/ANDROID/work/bin/classes
    [javac] /Users/admin/Dropbox/CODING/ANDROID/work/src/com/example/myfirstapp/DisplayMessageActivity.java:1: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol: class Activity
    [javac] public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {
    [javac]                                             ^
    [javac] /Users/admin/Dropbox/CODING/ANDROID/work/src/com/example/myfirstapp/DisplayMessageActivity.java:5: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class Bundle
    [javac] location: class DisplayMessageActivity
    [javac]     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] /Users/admin/Dropbox/CODING/ANDROID/work/src/com/example/myfirstapp/DisplayMessageActivity.java:23: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class MenuItem
    [javac] location: class DisplayMessageActivity
    [javac]     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    [javac]                                          ^
    [javac] /Users/admin/Dropbox/CODING/ANDROID/work/src/com/example/myfirstapp/DisplayMessageActivity.java:3: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class SuppressLint
    [javac] location: class DisplayMessageActivity
    [javac]     @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    [javac]      ^
    [javac] /Users/admin/Dropbox/CODING/ANDROID/work/src/com/example/myfirstapp/DisplayMessageActivity.java:7: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable super
    [javac] location: class DisplayMessageActivity
    [javac]         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    [javac]         ^
    [javac] /Users/admin/Dropbox/CODING/ANDROID/work/src/com/example/myfirstapp/DisplayMessageActivity.java:10: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class Intent
    [javac] location: class DisplayMessageActivity
    [javac]         Intent intent = getIntent();
    [javac]         ^
    [javac] /Users/admin/Dropbox/CODING/ANDROID/work/src/com/example/myfirstapp/DisplayMessageActivity.java:10: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method getIntent()
    [javac] location: class DisplayMessageActivity
    [javac]         Intent intent = getIntent();
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /Users/admin/Dropbox/CODING/ANDROID/work/src/com/example/myfirstapp/DisplayMessageActivity.java:11: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable MainActivity
    [javac] location: class DisplayMessageActivity
    [javac]         String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    [javac]                                                ^
    [javac] /Users/admin/Dropbox/CODING/ANDROID/work/src/com/example/myfirstapp/DisplayMessageActivity.java:14: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class TextView
    [javac] location: class DisplayMessageActivity
    [javac]         TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    [javac]         ^
    [javac] /Users/admin/Dropbox/CODING/ANDROID/work/src/com/example/myfirstapp/DisplayMessageActivity.java:14: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class TextView
    [javac] location: class DisplayMessageActivity
    [javac]         TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    [javac]                                 ^
    [javac] /Users/admin/Dropbox/CODING/ANDROID/work/src/com/example/myfirstapp/DisplayMessageActivity.java:4: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] /Users/admin/Dropbox/CODING/ANDROID/work/src/com/example/myfirstapp/DisplayMessageActivity.java:26: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable NavUtils
    [javac] location: class DisplayMessageActivity
    [javac]             NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /Users/admin/Dropbox/CODING/ANDROID/work/src/com/example/myfirstapp/DisplayMessageActivity.java:29: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable super
    [javac] location: class DisplayMessageActivity
    [javac]         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    [javac]                ^
    [javac] /Users/admin/Dropbox/CODING/ANDROID/work/src/com/example/myfirstapp/DisplayMessageActivity.java:22: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] /Users/admin/Dropbox/CODING/ANDROID/work/src/com/example/myfirstapp/MainActivity.java:21: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class Intent
    [javac] location: class com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity
    [javac]         Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    [javac]         ^
    [javac] /Users/admin/Dropbox/CODING/ANDROID/work/src/com/example/myfirstapp/MainActivity.java:21: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class Intent
    [javac] location: class com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity
    [javac]         Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    [javac]                             ^
    [javac] /Users/admin/Dropbox/CODING/ANDROID/work/src/com/example/myfirstapp/DisplayMessageActivity.java:1: duplicate class: DisplayMessageActivity
    [javac] public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {
    [javac]        ^
    [javac] /Users/admin/Dropbox/CODING/ANDROID/work/src/com/example/myfirstapp/MainActivity.java:21: cannot access com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity
    [javac] bad class file: /Users/admin/Dropbox/CODING/ANDROID/work/src/com/example/myfirstapp/DisplayMessageActivity.java
    [javac] file does not contain class com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity
    [javac] Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
    [javac]         Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    [javac]                                          ^
    [javac] 18 errors

BUILD FAILED
/Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I have searched high and low for someone facing this particular issue on Stack Overflow, but found no resolution. I thought that it may just be a case of the tutorial not including the correct import statements. I have tried several different imports, but always end up with some type of compile time error.

If anyone has a solution to how this tutorial must be implemented to work correctly, It will almost certainly preserve the last dying embers of my sanity.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The fact that you get "Activity" not found points to a problem with locating the Android libraries. Are you sure you've set up everything correctly? What is the content of your ant.properties file?

Comment: My ant.properties file is currently empty. I thought everything needed for building was created in the build.xml that is auto-generated during android project creation, no? I've just ensured that ANDROID_HOME is also set, but this makes no difference to my compile time issues. What exactly should I be putting in the ant.properties file?

Comment: I believe that the path to the Android libraries should be in there, otherwise, the compiler won't be able to find them. I don't use the command-line anymore, so I'm a bit at a loss as to what needs to go in there. I found a link at http://playaprogrammer.blogspot.com/2013/01/android-build-configuration-tutorial.html that might help you out.